# How can I delete data of the current tab from an object in my background page in google chrome extension when the tab is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am working on a chrome extension in which I need to delete data of the tab stored in an object of key as tab-IDs as soon as the tab is either closed or refreshed. I am clearing the data in my background page and thus I need to know when the tab is refreshed. 
For now I am using **window.onbeforeunload** function in my srcipt which is injected to the page using the content script to check for refresh of the page. Here is my **injected_script.js** code

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function (event) {
    console.log("page is unloading");
    var tosend={};
    tosend['type']="Page unload";
    window.postMessage(tosend,"*");
});
```

With the help of this I am sending a message to content_script.js which in turn sends the message to my background.js to alert the background of page refresh. 
Here is my **content_script.js** code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function () {
    window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
            if (event.source != window)
                return;

            if (event.data.type && (event.data['type'] == "Page unload")) {
                // alert('message is going to be send');
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(event.data, function (response) {
                });

            }
        }, false);
},false);
```

Now in my **background.js** I have the following code which deletes the value of the particular tabid from the **dataStore** object like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
if(message['type']==="Page unload"){
            console.log("here is data going to be deleted"+ ' '+ sender.tab.id);
            delete dataStore[sender.tab.id];
        }
        return true;

    });
// In case of tabs get closed
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (tabId) {
        console.log("tab removed !");
        delete dataStore[sender.tab.id];

    });
```

Here is my **manifest.json** code

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"Browsing Analyser",
  "description":"A simple chrome extension to keep track of time you spend on different websites",
  "version":"1.0",

  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":[
    "tabs","background","storage","notifications","webRequest", "webRequestBlocking","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "js":["content_script.js"],
      "matches":["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start"

    }
  ],
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"],
    "persistent":true
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["own_modal.css","bootstrap.css" , "second_scr.js","icon.png"]

}
```

It works fine if I do this when the page DOM content is loaded i.e the injected script gets loaded but if I refresh it before that, the data gets appended to the old data instead of replacing it. 
The data which I am talking about is chrome web request calls which come as soon as the page starts to load. 
All I want is how to alert background page that the page is refreshed so that it clears the old data and starts loading the new one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using chrome.tabs.onRemoved but not chrome.tabs.onUpdated, which supposedly should help in this case, why?

Comment: Because chrome.tabs.onUpdated gets called multiple times when we have refreshed a page only once. So basically it deletes the data which is useful.
P.S:- I have tried that too actually.

Comment: and even if i use changeInfo.status == 'complete',then it won't be able to listen all the web requests that it should listen to ideally.